# initialize linked list at compile time

Tags: c, struct

i have the following struct:

```
struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

I want to initialize it with some already known values.

E.g:

```
struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
} *root = &(struct node){"data1", &(struct node){"data2", NULL}};
```

It's possible to get the address of the struct that contains "data2"?
or to assign root to the struct that contains "data2"?

Edit:

I want to make the following at compile time with compound literals:

```
struct node *b = &(struct node){"data2", NULL};
struct node *a = &(struct node){"data1", b};
a = b;
```

Edit2:

something like that:

```
struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *tmp, *root = &(struct node){"data1", tmp = &(struct node){"data2", root}};
root = tmp;
```

but i do not want tmp to exist at run time

Comment: The question is rather unclear. Does your code work? If not, what is the error or unwanted behaviour?

Comment: `root` has type `struct node *`, so it can't point to the `next` or `data` fields of an instance of `struct node` without circumventing the type system (and even if it could, it would be useless).  If you have an actual instance of `struct node` (as opposed to just a pointer), then you could make a pointer point to it, or you could assign the current value of the `next` field to the pointer.  But there is no instance in the posted code.

Comment: OsourceAll,  How about `struct node root1 = {"Hello World", &root1};`.  `&root1` can be used in later code where a pointer is needed.

Comment: `static struct node {...} a = { 'a', 0 }, b = { 'b', &a }, c = { 'c', &b };` works for `clang -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Weverything`, but I'm still not sure that taking the address of variables in this way is portable. Good question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct node { char *data; struct node *next; }
        b = {"data2", NULL}, a = {"data1", &b}, *root = &b;

int
main(void)
{
        printf("%s\n", root->data);
        return 0;
}
```

or perhaps:

```
struct node { char *data; struct node *next; };
struct node *a = &(struct node){"data1", &(struct node){"data2", NULL}} ;

int
main(void)
{
        struct node *b = a->next;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I've modified the code; are you saying you want `struct node *root = &c`?

Comment: @OsourceAll Edited the solution to perhaps give you what you want.  It's not quite there, though.

Comment: But I don't understand why you are declaring your object to be pointer types instead of just doing: `struct node { char *data; struct node *next; } b = {"data2", NULL}, a = {"data1", &b};`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialise two different pointers to the same object statically, you have to name that object and use its address. For example:

```
struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
};

char last_data[] = "last_data";
char* last_data_ptr = last_data;
struct node last_node = (struct node){last_data, NULL};
struct node* last_node_ptr = &last_node;
struct node* list = &(struct node){"first_data", &last_node};
```

Here `&last_node` is used twice, once to initialise `last_node_ptr` and once to initialize a field in an unnamed struct that is used to initialise `list`. Likewise, `last_data` is used twice, once for `last_data_ptr` and once for a field in `last_node`. You cannot do that with a literal. It can only initialise one variable.

Here's how once can build a circular linked list:

```
struct node
{
    char* data;
    struct node* next;
} list = {"one", &(struct node){"two", &(struct node){"three", &list}}};
struct node *root = &list;
```

Comment: "initialize root to the value of its next field" doesn't seem to have any sense to me. The root and its next field are two different things. If you want to have a node with the next field that points to some "next" node, and another pointer named "root" that points to that same "next" node, read the answer again. If you want `root` to be a pointer to a pointer to `struct node` and make it point to the address of a field of some node, then no, it is not possible.

Comment: If you want a circular linked list, why not say that you want a circular linked list right tn the question?

Comment: The example of having the address of the last node was in the answer from the very beginning. Your updates don't have much sense to me, sorry. They leak static memory and create uninitialised pointers.

Comment: `struct node last_node = (struct node){last_data, NULL};` It is there and was there all the time. But it is true that I have no idea what you really want.